# How to say "No" to pay deductions?

Tags: salary, united-kingdom

I work for a company that designs and builds fitted furniture. We also offer a free survey service to our customers and normally arrange for a third party to fit the furniture.

I sold some furniture to a customer who wanted to buy the furniture and fit it himself He provided all the measurements required himself and turned down the survey.

Now the customer has contacted our customer service department to complain that the furniture is the wrong size.

Now my employer wants me to pay for the incorrect furniture. My contract doesn't state anything about pay deductions and I am in the UK so there are limitations on what my employer can deduct.

**How should I tell my employer that I am not going to pay?**

Comment: Is the customer correct? Do you have measurements and correspondence etc,. If you do then just tell the employer it's not your problem, you delivered what was asked. If you don't... why don't you? Either way thats central to the question, we need this info

Comment: This would be a good time to revise your terms of service to include some sort of limited liability or indemnity clause for just these sorts of work orders. For future protection. Also, check your current ToS and see if there's anything like that.

Comment: Sounds unreasonable to me

Answer (score 7):

You tell him "I am not going to pay". Why would your employer compensate a customer for incorrect furniture if it is obviously the customers fault?

Your employer *must* pay your salary. He has no right to deduct anything. If he wishes, he can ask you to pay for damages; if you refuse, he can take you to court. But first, he must pay.